# create distorted polygon box2d body from rectangular texture region

Tags: android, box2d, sprite, andengine

I have a rectangular sprite. I have created a polygon body. I cut it and I have obtained the coordinates of the polygons that needs to be created. challenge for me is to create that distorted (somewhat similar to unaligned triangle) polygon using that rectangular texture area.

I think this concept is somewhat related to cropping a body or a sprite or cropping a texture region.

by the way i have tried creating the body with those resultant coordinates. body's physical properties are according to the coordinates but it does not crop the texture visually. it shows me the whole rectangle :(

Any help would be appreciable.

[image: My polygon body was abcd, now i have cut the body i want to create two bodies abd and bcd using the same texture region.]